# Undefined method skills_path Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a new skill in my belongs_to and has_many through relationship.

```
class Row < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :timeframe, required: false
  belongs_to :map, required: false
  belongs_to :standard, required: false
  belongs_to :content, required: false
  belongs_to :skill, required: false
  belongs_to :resource, required: false
  belongs_to :assignment, required: false
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rows
  has_many :maps, through: :rows
end
```

I want to create a new skill under a row so I created the following route to do so.

resources :rows do
    resources :skills
  end

If I do a rake routes I see that I need to use the following route to create that skill under the row. `new_row_skill_path`

If I use this link_to I would like it to go to the form to create that form.

`<%= link_to '+', new_row_skill_path(row), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>`

This is the form I am using:

```
<%= form_with(model: skill, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :skill %>
    <%= form.text_field :skill, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

However when I am clicking that add button I get this error. 
`undefined method`skills_path'`

Does this have something to do with me using the form_with(model: skill)? I tried custom writing a route under the rows do like so but I am still getting that error.

```
resources :rows do
  get 'rows/:id/skills/new', to: 'skills#new'
end
```

## Skills controller

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @skill = Skill.new
  end

  def create
    @skill = Skill.new(skill_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @skill.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Skill created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'That shit failed.' }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def skill_params
      params.require(:skill).permit(:skill_id, :skills)
    end
end
```

Comment: have you made an action to `create` to submit form all data? can you share controller code?

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file, go back to using:

```
resources :rows do
  resources :skills
end
```

Then try specifying a `url` like so:

`<%= form_with(model: skill, local: true, url: row_skills_path) do |form| %>`

Comment: Using your answer I get the following error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"skills", :row_id=>"4"}, missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: I had a typo in my answer that I think is causing this error. The `url` should be set to `row_skills_path`. I've corrected this in the answer.

Comment: That update worked. For some reason I can't get the row to update with the skill id that was created. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Post your `SkillsController` code and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Added. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question do get help with updating the appropriate `row` record when creating a new `skill`. Since we have the routing and URL problem fixed, which was your initial question, creating a new question would probably be best.